# zsh: SHARE_HISTORY or INC_APPEND_HISTORY breaks EXTENDED_HISTORY

Tags: zsh, configuration, command-history, timestamps

I would like to both share history across terminals and keep track of elapsed time for history commands. The intuitive way seems to be to use both `EXTENDED_HISTORY` and `SHARE_HISTORY`, but this sets all elapsed timestamps to 0 after restarting the shell. Is this the correct way to do it? Is it even possible?

### Scenario 1: `EXTENDED_HISTORY` and `SHARE_HISTORY`

```sh
$ history -Dn | sed 's|\\n|\n      |g'
0:00  cat << EOF > ~/.zshrc
          HISTFILE=~/.zhistory-test
          HISTSIZE=100
          SAVEHIST=100
          setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY
          setopt SHARE_HISTORY # the only change compared to below
      EOF
0:00  exec zsh
```

**`0:00`**`sleep 1`

```sh
0:00  exec zsh
```

### Scenario 2: only `EXTENDED_HISTORY`

```sh
$ history -Dn | sed 's|\\n|\n      |g'
0:00  cat << EOF > ~/.zshrc
          HISTFILE=~/.zhistory-test
          HISTSIZE=100
          SAVEHIST=100
          setopt EXTENDED_HISTORY
      EOF
0:00  exec zsh
```

**`0:01`**`sleep 1`

```sh
0:00  exec zsh
```

### Scenario 3: `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` and `SHARE_HISTORY`

Same as scenario 1, but replacing `SHARE_HISTORY` with `INC_APPEND_HISTORY` seems to have the same effect.

### System info

**`$ zsh --version`**

```
zsh 5.4.2 (x86_64-unknown-linux-musl)
```

**`$ ldd /usr/bin/zsh`**

```
        /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f0f8b1d8000)
        libcap.so.2 => /lib/libcap.so.2 (0x7f0f8acfa000)
        libncursesw.so.6 => /lib/libncursesw.so.6 (0x7f0f8aa89000)
        libc.so => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f0f8b1d8000)
```

**`$ uname -a`**

```
Linux hostname 4.12.13_1 #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 14 13:15:00 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**`$ lsb_release -d`**

```
Description:    Void Linux
```

Comment: I was looking for this too. I like how INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME works, but it doesn't appear to work with SHARE_HISTORY. I guess we are looking for a SHARE_HISTORY_TIME.

Comment: @whatsthatitspat What do you think of my answer?

Answer (score 3):

I’ve tested several ways of trying to share extended history between multiple terminal sessions and this is the only one that seems to work flawlessly:

```bash
autoload -Uz add-zsh-hook

setopt extendedhistory incappendhistorytime

load-shared-history() {
  # Pop the current history off the history stack, so we don't grow
  # the history stack endlessly
  fc -P

  # Load a new history from $HISTFILE and push it onto the history 
  # stack.
  fc -p $HISTFILE
}

# Import the latest history at the start of each new command line.
add-zsh-hook precmd load-shared-history
```

Now all you need to do to sync your history in any terminal session is to press Enter.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try doing fc -RI? That's what the zsh manual recommends as the way to "manually" load history when not using SHARE_HISTORY.

Comment: It’s been two years since I answered this, but as far as I recall, nothing else I tried would keep the recorded times of your commands intact, which is what OP asked for. You’re welcome to test this yourself, though.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at it, the downside is that of course the commands don't become available in your history until they complete. So if you want to quickly launch a few long running commands, it may be a bit more annoying. The ideal IMHO would actually be to have two history files: one that doesn't save durations, one that does. Search for historical commands in the former, search for durations (when you need them) in the latter. I may look into it; I don't think it's that bad.

Answer (score 1):

The only option you need is `SHARE_HISTORY`

Here's a [video of shared history working](https://i.imgur.com/vh3MEE4.mp4)

And here's the documentation [linked](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Options.html#History) + quoted

> This option both imports new commands from the history file, and also causes your typed commands to be appended to the history file (the latter is like specifying INC_APPEND_HISTORY, which should be turned off if this option is in effect). The history lines are also output with timestamps ala EXTENDED_HISTORY (which makes it easier to find the spot where we left off reading the file after it gets re-written).
>
> By default, history movement commands visit the imported lines as well as the local lines, but you can toggle this on and off with the set-local-history zle binding. It is also possible to create a zle widget that will make some commands ignore imported commands, and some include them.
>
> If you find that you want more control over when commands get imported, you may wish to turn SHARE_HISTORY off, INC_APPEND_HISTORY or INC_APPEND_HISTORY_TIME (see above) on, and then manually import commands whenever you need them using ‘fc -RI’.